# ParseInt Prompt not displaying in Table

Tags: javascript, html, html-table, document.write

Any help would be greatly appreciated, I'm currently having issues with user input by prompt, to be saved as a variable so it can go through a for loop and then inserted into a table. I'm sure my mistake is in the way I'm formatting the insert into the table.

```
var investment = parseInt(prompt("What will be your initial investment?", "0"), 10);
var interest_rate = parseInt(prompt("What will be your interest rate?", "0"), 10);
var deposit_amount = parseInt(prompt("What will be your monthly deposit?", "0"), 10);
var start_age = parseInt(prompt("What is your age?", "0"), 10);
var beg_balance    = 0;
var end_balance    = 0;
var daily_interest_rate = interest_rate / 365;
var calculated_interest = 0;
var accrued_interest    = 0;
var cumulative_deposits = 0;
var day           = 0;


document.write("<table>")
document.write("<tr><th>Age</th><th>Beg Balance</th><th>Interest</th><th>Deposits</th><th>Ending Balance</th></tr>")

beg_balance = investment;

for (var yearly = start_age + 1; yearly <= end_age; yearly++) 
{
    for (var daily = 1; daily <= 365; daily++) 
    {
        day++;
        calculated_interest = (daily_interest_rate) * (beg_balance + cumulative_deposits + accrued_interest);

        accrued_interest += calculated_interest;

        if (day == 30) 
        {
        day = 0;
        cumulative_deposits += deposit_amount;
        }     
    }

end_balance = beg_balance + cumulative_deposits + accrued_interest;

document.write("<tr>");

document.write("<td>" + yearly.toFixed(2) + "</td><td>" + beg_balance.toFixed(2) + "</td><td>" + accrued_interest.toFixed(2) + "</td><td>" + cumulative_deposits.toFixed(2) + "</td><td>" +      end_balance.toFixed(2) + "</td>");

document.write("</tr>");

beg_balance = end_balance;
cumulative_deposits = 0;
accrued_interest = 0;       
}  
document.write("</table>")
```

Comment: Document.write is NOT like writing a string, when you write an opening tag, the browser will close it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is no "end_age" defined. There is nothing to loop through.

Comment: Wow. Thank you so much. It printed the code and now to tweak the formula.

Comment: I'm glad it worked for you. Please accept the answer if you are satisfied.